# Understanding std::pair <const T&, const U&>

Tags: c++, std-pair

I am trying to create a class that instantiates an `std::pair<const T&, const U&>` from two member variables. I started this out of curiosity and was surprised to see the results from creating multiple objects of, in the example below, `Pair`.

```cpp
struct Pair {
    int num;
    string s;
    pair<const int&, const string&> pr{make_pair(num, s)};

    Pair(int n, const string& s) : num(n), s(s) {}
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Pair& p) {
    out  << setw(2) << p.num << ", "  << p.s << ": <" << p.pr.first << "," << p.pr.second << ">";
    return out;
}

/******************************************************************************/
int main() {

    cout << string(15, '-') << " PIECEMEAL " << string(15, '-') << endl;
    Pair p1{1, "normal1"};
    Pair p2{2, "normal2"};
    cout << p1 << endl;
    cout << p2 << endl << endl;

    cout << string(15, '-') << "  VECTOR " << string(15, '-') << endl;
    vector<Pair> v;
    for (int i=0; i< 05; ++i) {
        v.emplace_back(i, "from_vec'" + ::to_string(i) + "'");
    }

    for(const auto & p : v) {
        cout << p << endl;
    }
}
```

I thought that the `const` reference type declarations within the `pair` would refer to the `Pair` members, `num` and `s`, respectively. However, when I create multiple `Pair`s, it appears that the references within the `pair` end up referencing (to some degree) the `Pair` members of the most recently constructed `Pair`.

Here is the output:

```
--------------- PIECEMEAL ---------------
 1, normal1: <2,normal2>
 2, normal2: <1586964272,normal2>

---------------  VECTOR ---------------
 0, from_vec'0': <4,from_vec'4'>
 1, from_vec'1': <1586964272,from_vec'4'>
 2, from_vec'2': <1586964272,from_vec'4'>
 3, from_vec'3': <1586964272,from_vec'4'>
 4, from_vec'4': <1586964272,from_vec'4'>
```

I looked at [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair) in an attempt to understand what was going on, but still not grasping it.
Why do the references within the `pair` no longer reference the `Pair` members, `num` and `s`?

Comment: `make_pair(num, s)` is `make_pair<int,string>(num, s)`, which return `std::pair<int,string>`

Comment: @appleapple maybe I'm missing something, but how does that address why the references in each `pair` no longer reference the `Pair` members?

Comment: basically you're under UB as the temporary already destroyed.

Comment: You are creating a temporary `pair<int,string>`.  Then you are making your `pair<const int&, const string&>` reference it.  Then the temporary `pair<int,string>` is destroyed and you have dangling references.  `pr` is **never** referencing `num` and `s`.  Change `pr{make_pair(num, s)}` to `pr{num, s}`

Comment: Or better, drop num and s, and declare pr as a pair<int, string>.

Comment: Also, for correct work with vector you need to define at least move constructor (default one is not good for this case) and define or delete copy constructor and copy/move assignment operators.

Comment: Another problem - even if the `Pair` constructor initialized the `std::pair` member correctly, when pushing `Pair` instances into the `std::vector`, it is possible that the references stored in existing `Pair`s would get invalidated whenever the `std::vector` reallocates its internal array. `Pair` needs a copy constructor and move constructor to ensure the `std::pair` member always refers to valid members.

Comment: Sorry, but not understanding fully. I understand that, in reality, I would create a copy and move ctor. What I am still not understanding is that I thought that by initializing the pair with references to persistent members of ``Pair``, that the values within the ``std::pair`` would reference ``num`` and ``s``. 
[see ast example here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair). Thanks

Comment: Additionally, a minor issue, but `s` is *shadowed* in `Pair(int n, const string& s) : num(n), s(s) {}`, perhaps `Pair(int n, const string& str) : num(n), s(str) {}`. Compiling with `-Wshadow` on gcc or the equivalent on other compilers would disclose the issue immediately.

Comment: In `pair<const int&, const string&> pr{make_pair(num, s)};` the `make_pair()` constructs a temporary `std::pair<int, std::string>`, and `pr` is initialised with references to members of that temporary i.e. to dangling references, since that temporary then ceases to exist.  Subsequent usage of that references then gives undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 problems with your code.

---

First:

```cpp
pair<const int&, const string&> pr{make_pair(num, s)}
```

`std::make_pair(num, s)` first create a temporary `pair<int, string>`. Then `pr` will be initialized with this temporary `pair`.

Note that `pair<int, string>` is not the same as `pari<const int&, const string&>`, which means it will not trigger the default move constructor.

Instead, if you looked at [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair), this would trigger the 6th overload, and essentially assign `pr.first` and `pr.second` with this temporary `pair`, hence dangling reference.

To fix it, you should specifically create a `pair` of references with:

```cpp
pr{std::make_pair(std::ref(num), std::ref(s)}
```

Or just create `pr` directly with `num` and `s`:

```cpp
pr{num, s}
```

---

Second:

```cpp
v.emplace_back(i, "from_vec'" + ::to_string(i) + "'");
```

This line would trigger the default move constructor, since you didn't specify one yourself, which would perform a member-wise move on `Pair`.

However, what happens when you move `pr` to the new `Pair`? The old `pr` was referencing the old `num` and old `s`. Moving the old `pr` to the new `Pair` doesn't change the value of `pr`, hence it will continue referencing the old `num` and old `s`, hence dangling reference.

So instead of relying on default generated move constructors, you must define them manually:

```cpp
Pair(Pair&& pair) noexcept
: num(std::exchange(pair.num, {})
, s(std::move(pair.s))
{}
```

Note, you don't need to construct `pr` within initializer list since you already have a default initializer for `pr`.

---

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qvc5z5rW3)

Comment: Very helpful. So, am I correct in assuming that ``std::make_pair`` creates a copy based upon this: 
[The deduced types V1 and V2 are std::decay<T1>::type and std::decay<T2>::type (the usual type transformations applied to arguments of functions passed by value) unless application of std::decay results in std::reference_wrapper<X> for some type X, in which case the deduced type is X&.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair#:~:text=types%20of%20arguments.-,The,-deduced%20types%20V1)? Which would also explain why passing `std::ref` also works?

Comment: @trozzel You are correct. Unless the types are `reference_wrapper`s, it will always result into value types.

Answer (score 0):

You are inadvertently creating a pair that holds const references to another pair that was allocated on the stack and immediately freed. In other words, undefined behavior.

Step by step, here's what's happening when you instantiate a Pair:

1. The Pair constructor is called.
2. The Pair initializer is called.
3. The initializer calls make_pair, creating a pair of int and std::string on the stack.
4. This temporary pair gets assigned to pr, and the const references inside it now refer to the memory of the temporary pair.
5. The initializer exits, freeing the temporary pair on the stack. the int and string references inside pr now refer to memory that has been freed.

What's more, you really shouldn't be storing references to other members inside your struct, for memory safety reasons. If you want a std::pair of your two values, you should make a member function that returns it instead of storing it inside the struct itself.

Comment: I couldn't see before why the `make_pair` was copying the values, even though I *thought* I was passing them by const reference. Also, not understanding the nature of `std::decay` and that the values in the `pair` are passed as `std::decay<decltype(T)>::type` and `std::decay<decltype(U)>::type`, thus removing [removing cv type qualification](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay#:~:text=.-,Otherwise,-%2C%20the%20member%20typedef).